# Protractor code shared among several test suits

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm working with protractor (in combination with Jasmine) and I would like to test application which requires login. I tried to search here and I have found one solution which suggested to put login code into beforeEach method on test suite. Isn't there any other way? 
I will test lets say 20 pages, so I need to login only once, at the beginning of the testing. 
Not before each test suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your login in an `onPrepare` function, in your config file, that will get run once before any of your test runs. See the example [withLoginConf.js](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/withLoginConf.js)